# Iphone secondary xib, UIWebview local htm file will not load. I have tried numerous methods nothing has worked

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, xib

I am loading as secondary view with its own xib file.  I can load it fine, but cannot get the webview in it to load any content.  I have another app where this proces works, but it is in the main view.

Here is the code I am using.

```
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"workshop" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:@"dirA"];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
       [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// to make html content transparent to its parent view -
// 1) set the webview's backgroundColor property to [UIColor clearColor]
// 2) use the content in the html: <body style="background-color: transparent">
// 3) opaque property set to NO
//
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
[htmlString release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}





-(IBAction)switchCanary {

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)switchBack {

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Please edit to make the code readable.  Four spaces before each line with code will put the code into a code block.

Comment: Have you connected the webView IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes,  I double checked.  I can get the webView to load, and it has the transparent properties I want.  It just displays no content.  I have the .htm file in the same directory as where I have it in my other app as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  For some reason I was able to load .htm files before.  I had to change them all to .html and now it works.  Maybe a recent change.  The other app was a couple SDK versions ago.